# How can I rename files of with different files extensions using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a folder containing 106 images. Of these, 15 have a '.jpg' extension and the other 91 have a '.tif' extension.  I want to rename the files sequentially so that they all have the '.tif' extension.  I am able to rename the files with same extension (.jpg) using the following code:

```
 a = 'D\newfolder';
 A = dir(fullfile(a,'*.jpg'));
 fileNames = {A.name};
 for iFile = 1:numel(A)
    newName = fullfile(a,sprintf('%0d.jpg',iFile));
    movefile(fullfile(a,fileNames{iFile}),newName);
end
```

This code works fine for images with the '.jpg' extension.  However, now I have both '.tif' and '.jpg' file extensions in the same folder.  I want to rename them and apply further operations to them within a loop.  How can I modify this code to rename both '.tif' and '.jpg' files sequentially and with '.tif' as the renamed files' extension?

Comment: Do you want to keep the extension as a .tif?  Is the order supposed to go from 1 to 106 for all file names regardless of extension or is it okay to have 1.jpg to 15.jpg and then 1.tif to 91.tif?

Comment: I have to keep the extension of all 106 files to tiff. I want to change jpg files to tiff. After that order should to be from 1 to 106.

Comment: Is it '.tif' like you say in your post or 'tiff' like you say in your comment?  Let me know, and I'll put it that way in my answer.

Comment: it is 'tif'. Sorry for typo.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: So you're going to change the file extension without changing the image format? That sounds like it's not going to work.

Comment: Good point beaker. I was assuming the files were just incorrectly named in the first place.  Perhaps this what they mean by applying further operations to the them within the loop.

Comment: @informaton I just tried it. It renamed the files correctly sequentially uptill 106. Does changing the extension and changing image format is different. I want to make both image files of same type so I can read them later by a single loop. That's why I want to make them of same extension.

Comment: @sidraaleem Glad to hear it.  Yes, changing the extension and changing the image format is different.  The extension is typically just used as a hint indicating the image format for you or a program to know how the image is actually encoded.  I'll update my answer with a link on how you can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that stays close to your current one:

```
A = dir(fullfile(a,'*.jpg'));
B = dir(fullfile(a,'*.tif'));

fileNames = {A.name,B.name};
for iFile = 1:numel(fileNames)
    newName = fullfile(a,sprintf('%0d.tif',iFile));
    movefile(fullfile(a,fileNames{iFile}),newName);    
end
```

Where `a` is the folder you have defined already.

**UPDATE**

The file extension '.jpg' and '.tif' are just labels indicating the image format expected within that file.  There are just labels though and can be wrong.  For example if you gave these files a '.txt' extension they do not suddenly become text files, though you are more likely to be able to open them up in a text editor and verify.

That being said, many image loaders will first verify the image format directly from the file (and not the extension) and use the corresponding *codec* to load it.  So the mismatch in format and file extension may not actually matter in practice, but you are relying a bit on chance.

You can transcode your jpeg formatted images to tiff format directly however.  A similar question was asked at [The Mathworks site](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/63586-how-can-i-change-image-file-format-from-jpg-to-tiff).

Essentially you would read the file and then write it in the new format.  Here's how you can change the above code to do it:

```
A = dir(fullfile(a,'*.jpg'));
B = dir(fullfile(a,'*.tif'));

fileNames = {A.name,B.name};
for iFile = 1:numel(fileNames)
    [~,~, fileExt] = fileparts(fileNames{iFile});
    if(strcmpi(fileExt,'.jpg'))
        fullJpegFilename = fullfile(a,fileNames{iFile});
        tmpImg = imread(fullJpegFilename); % read jpeg format
        imwrite(tmpImg,fullfile(a,sprintf('%0d.tif',iFile)); % write file as .tif format
        delete(fullJpegFilename);  % no longer needed            
    else
        newName = fullfile(a,sprintf('%0d.tif',iFile));
        movefile(fullfile(a,fileNames{iFile}),newName);    
    end
end
```